# Medir o uso de um código Python na CPU e Memoria

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho um código e quero saber quanto que ele ta pegando do processador e da memoria.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+Esc no Windows 10 e analise o processo python.exe

Comment: Este comando abre o Gerenciador de Tarefas

Comment: Mas lá ira mostrar os dados em tempo de execução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se não for utilizar gerenciador de tarefas, podes usar a biblioteca psutils

```
import psutil 

print(psutil.cpu_percent())                    # Em porcentagem, uso da CPU
print(psutil.virtual_memory()._asdict())       # Em dicionário informações de memória física
```

retorna, por exemplo:

> 14.2
>
> OrderedDict([('total', 8272900096), ('available', 3767132160),
>   ('percent', 54.5), ('used', 4505767936), ('free', 3767132160)])

**Edit:** Há uma abordagem por id de processo também, "um pouco' mais complexa caso essa não lhe agrade.